# Why was damage denoted in ranges in older D&D editions?

Tags: damage, dice, adnd-1e, designer-reasons

In early editions of Dungeons and Dragons, monster damage was denoted as a range of possible outcomes, for example, if a monster dealt 3d6 of damage, it would state the monster dealt 3-18 damage. You had to divide the larger number by the smaller mentally, to find out what dice to use (here 18/3 = 6, so d6).

Later editions moved to spelling out the dice directly, for example they would state the monster deals 3d6 damage. I personally find this easier, as it saves you the need to mentally derive what dice to use.

Is there anything known about why the damage originally was not denoted as 3d6?

Comment: A bit of relevant trivia: the 1e Monster Manual II included a table in the "How to use this book" section that mapped the number ranges to actual dice to roll. Interestingly, that table had *two* entries for 3–12: 3d4, and d10+2.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Going by the Wikipedia article on [Dice Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation), the answer is simply that it hadn't been invented yet.

Quoting the article:

> Miniatures wargamers began using dice in the shape of Platonic solids in the late 1960s and early ’70s, to obtain results that could not easily be produced on a conventional six-sided die. Dungeons & Dragons emerged in this milieu, and was the first game with widespread commercial availability to use such dice. In its earliest edition (1974), D&D had no standardized way to call for polyhedral die rolls or to refer to the results of such rolls. In some places the text gives a verbal instruction; in others, it only implies the roll to be made by describing the range of its results. For example, the spell sticks to snakes says, "From 2–16 snakes can be conjured (roll two eight-sided dice)." When only a range is listed, the exact method of rolling can be ambiguous. For example, a typical random wilderness encounter might be a village of "30–300" orcs. A number in that range might be generated by rolling 3d10×10, or alternately by rolling 30d10.
>
> D&D player Ted Johnstone introduced standard dice notation as a way to discuss probability distribution in an article, "Dice as Random Number Generators", in the inaugural issue of fanzine Alarums & Excursions (1975). The notation was also used by another writer, Barry Gold, in the same issue, and quickly spread throughout the fan community. Eventually, standard dice notation became so deeply ingrained in D&D fan culture that Gary Gygax would adopt it as a commonplace in the first edition of Advanced Dungeons & Dragons (1977-1979). The close association between D&D fandom and standard dice notation is reflected in the name of the Open Game version of the D&D rules: the "d20 System."

Comment: This can't be the complete story, because they were still showing only ranges in the AD&D 1st *and* 2nd edition monster stat blocks.

Comment: By then it was just how it was done, I expect. Tradition.

Comment: The 1st edition Monster Manual (1977) does not use the d notation. The PHB (1978) and DMG (1979) use them inconsistently, usually in tables with ranges or dice names “six-sided” in text.

Comment: The 1979 DMG has a whole section in the Introduction on dice mechanics; it's probably assumed that the DM has read it, understood it, and can apply it to a range without spelling out the dice to use.

Answer (score 8):

I played in or knew of maybe a dozen D&D groups back then, and everyone knew what the numbers meant, or knew how to figure it out, or knew how to ask at the local game store where they found out about it from people playing. Anyone at the time could instantly see most ranges and know what to roll. When they changed to "D" notation, I don't think any old D&D player thought it was an improvement. For weird stuff, like those 30-300 orcs, it was understood that it wasn't exactly a roll (it's telling you the smallest and largest size, but as a GM you can choose, or roll however you want).

As examples, 2-12 is from craps, which everyone knows. Of course it's two 6-sided dice. Likewise 3-18 is obvious from character roll-up (we all rolled 3d6 for stats back then). Lots use two dice: 2-8 (2d4), 2-16 (2d8) and 2-20 (2d10). Those are easy. Multiple dice are easy since, as you note, the bottom # is how many and then you just divide -- 5-20 is clearly 5d4 (all D&D players were good at simple math back then). For adding, everyone knows 2-5 is d4+1. Other dice with adds are less common, but fun: 3-8 (d6+2) or 5-10 (d6+4, unless you want to flip 5 coins).

It's also not as if people didn't need to learn what "2d6" meant. I'd say if you asked non-gamers to roll "2-12" and "2d6", the "2-12" ones would figure it out faster.

Maybe most importantly, a range can be better. We can see 2-12 is a little better than 1-12 (more easily than 2d6 vs 1d12). 3-12 (3d4) is clearly another step better. Written as a range we can see 2-5 is as good as 1-6 (d4+1 vs. d6). I mean, when I see "d10+2" I'm not sure what it is until I decode it as 3-12.

Comment: Note that even your example shows the relative weakness of ranges compared to explicit roll: 3-12 as 3d4 and 3-12 as 1d10+2 are not equivalent, since the latter if uniformly distributed but the former is not (therefore, their applications can be expected to be different).

Comment: You made it sound like it was a choice, but it couldn't have been, because d notation didn't exist, if the other answer is right. And it looks like it is.

Comment: @Molot -- ah, I see it. Fixing. Thanks.

Comment: @Cerberus Yes, I put the multiple ways to get 3-12 on purpose. Glad you noticed. In practice the monster's claw attack might do 2-8, so clearly the 3-12 bite was adding 1 more d4. We also enjoyed "oh -- your group rolls it like that?", and talking about things like "3d4 is more likely to kill a 4hp kobold than d10+2". I tried that but cut it as it seemed too long.